# bean name conflict while running the spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

**Background**: I am working in a project named `com.x.myproject`. I have the dependency of two other packages `com.x.document` and `com.x.library`. both packages have the same class with name `QueueHelper`.

Now, In my project, I have to scan one other package `com.x.security` which internally scans `com.x`, something like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.x"})
@EnableCaching
public class Security {
.......
}
```

in com.x.myproject

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.x.myproject","com.x.security"}, excludeFilters={
      @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.x.document.*"),
      @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.x.library.*")}) 
public class MyProject{
.......
}
```

It all works fine when I use `excludefilters` in `com.x.security` but I want to use it in `com.x.myproject`

The **exception** which I got is

```
Annotation-specified bean name 'queueHelper' for bean class [com.x.library.utils.QueueHelper] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.x.document.utils.QueueHelper]
```

Comment: A not-individual solution might be a naming strategy: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0-m2/reference/html/naming-strategy.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three answers come to my mind:

1. Give a different names to `com.x.library.utils.QueueHelper` and `com.x.document.utils.QueueHelper` via the `@Component` annotation. Spring will use the simple class name by default for naming the beans. You can annotate one with `@Component('libraryQueueHelper')` and the other with `@Component('documentQueueHelper')`. However, now you'll have to give a `@Qualifier(<name>)` in each place you're autowiring these beans.
2. Exclude them in your module, like you do in your question and then change their names using `@Bean` annotated methods within a `@Configuration`. When using in the third module, you'll need to use a `@Qualifier` to autowire the correct bean.
3. Rename the classes. This is the best solution in this case, but since you asked this question, I guess it's not viable.

Comment: Thanks, actually I want to do changes only in my project due to some restrictions. So #3, is perfect solution but not in my case. I'll take a look on another two.